# How to set specific file or folder display in DocumentLibrary Display portlet in liferay

Tags: liferay

I want to have url to the liferay page, where DocLIbDisplay portlet is situated. And when i go to url, page opes and some selected file was displayed in portlet.

Comment: wat u want to do????post some code so i can figured it out??

Comment: i want to create url addres. If i go to this url liferay page will be open and portlet doclibDisplay will show some file entity, instead of default rootdir view.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the "Root Folder" in the Document Library Display configuration to show a particular directory contents, but you can't show just one file (unless it's in a folder on it's own).